# Scala: composition law counter example

Tags: scala, functional-programming, functor

I'm learning functional programming by using Scala language. I have read tutorial about functor that functor has 2 laws:

```
1. identity law: functor.map(x => x) ≡ functor
2. Composition law: functor.map(x => f(g(x))) ≡ functor.map(g).map(f)
```

The thing I don't know about composition law. I have a feeling that all function has this property: f(g(x)) = functor.map(g).map(f). Can we have an example that not obey this rule?

Thanks

Comment: What you call "Composition law" is actually called "Associativity Law": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor#Definition. There are many functor instances, but only one that satisfies this `f(g(x)) = functor.map(g).map(f)` so it's not a property inherent to functors.

Comment: I believe "Composition law" is correct. This appears consistent with the wikipedia article you linked to.

Comment: @pedrofurla [Associativity laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property#Definition) involve three elements and generally take the form `x <> (y <> z) = (x <> y) <> z` (where the associative operation is called `<>` here). Or, avoiding infix, it would be `h(x, h(y, z)) = h(h(x, y), z)`. The composition law of functors means that a functor is a kind of [homomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphism#Definition) (between categories). I believe "composition law" is a fairly reasonable term (since the homomorphism is on the composition operation).

Comment: It's a property of `map` that *for all functions f and g* the composition law holds. It's not a property of functions f and g. Some types have `map` that has this property. These types are functors. For other types you cannot write `map` with this property.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how `Set` violates the 2nd functor law (and therefore is not a functor, although at first it may seem like one):

```
case class Foo(s: String) {
  override def equals(obj: scala.Any): Boolean = obj match {
    case Foo(t) => s.toUpperCase == t.toUpperCase
    case _ => false
  }
}

val toFoo = (s: String) => Foo(s)
val fromFoo = (foo: Foo) => foo.s

val set = Set("something", "SOMETHING")

set.map(toFoo).map(fromFoo)     //  Set(something)
set.map(x => fromFoo(toFoo(x))) //  Set(something, SOMETHING)
```

Comment: It should be noted rhat this is only possible because Scala allows you to violate logic laws with user-defined equality. Once you allow equality that doesn't obey `forall f. x == y implies f(x) == f(y)` you unleash all kinds of demons.

Comment: The equation you're referring to is obeyed, however. For any two strings `a` and `b` that are equal, `Foo(a)` and `Foo(b)` are also equal. Breaking the logic law would be saying that there are cases where for two identical inputs, we get two different outputs, but that's not the case. I'm violating `forall f. f(x) == f(y) implies x == y` and that's fine (any surjection violates that; take `List.length` for example).

Comment: a == b doesn't entail fromFoo(a) == fromFoo(b) and this is what breaks the logic.

Comment: @n.m. "Logic laws" is a bit vague. The `equals` method defined here *is* an equivalence relation, which is sometimes enough. It is a bit rare that you want equality in the most literal, strictest sense of the word (which could be something like pointer equality or literal syntactic equality, depending on how you look at it and what kind of thing you're working with), so you often do need something weaker. The question is whether it is too weak (which this may well be, but I would say it depends on the context).

Comment: @DavidYoung  Logic isn't vague at all, it's a well established mathematical discipline that provides foundations of reasoning. Any old equivalence relation is sometimes enough, but it's not enough for equational reasoning which is what laws like `functor.map(x => f(g(x))) ≡ functor.map(g).map(f)` are about.

Comment: @n.m. There are multiple systems of logic. I cut off my quote there a bit. It should be more like '"violate logic laws" is a bit vague' (as to which logic is being used). Also, I would say that an equivalence relation can *sometimes* be enough for equational reasoning (not always, of course). Consider, for instance, [weak n-categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher_category_theory#Weak_higher_categories) where the category laws are given not by equalities, but by a weaker relation. Weak infinity groupoids (which are also weak in the same sense) are foundational in homotopy type theory.

Comment: @DavidYoung I'm afraid this is a bit too abstract for me, and quite certainly for the OP.

Comment: @ n.m. True that. And I agree about reverse direction; if you consider Foo as domain and String as codomain of function fromFoo, then that function is breaking the law. Still, I think I provided a valid example of how the functor law can be broken by non-functor types. Having isomorphic types with differently defined equalities may not be the smartest (and safest) thing to have, but it's not breaking the logic laws. I can have a class User with first and last name, and class Email with address = first + last, and have the email require uniqueness, but User not. Bad design, but that's it.